# Как правильно передать даты в Matplotlib для построения графика?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[Датасет](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/4ETSeTsr9s6ZFg)

Загружаю датафрейм:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Sales.csv', sep=';', index_col=None, parse_dates=['DT'])
```

При попытке отобразить график с значениями по x в формате datetime64[ns]:

```
plt.plot(df['DT'], df['Sales'])
```

получаю:

[image: По х datetime]

при попытке передать в формате Matplotlib

```
plt.plot(matplotlib.dates.date2num(df['DT']), df['Sales'])
```

результат тот же

При отображении графика с значениями по x в формате object:

```
plt.plot(df['DT'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), df['Sales'])
```

отображает верно:
[image: По x object]

**Как правильно передать даты в Matplotlib** в формате datetime64[ns] для построения графика?

Comment: Ваша проблема не воспроизводиться, выдается только предупреждение `UserWarning: Parsing dates in %d.%m.%Y format when dayfirst=False (the default) was specified. Pass `dayfirst=True` or specify a format to silence this warning.
  df = pd.read_csv('Sales.csv', sep=';', index_col=None, parse_dates=['DT'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо таки обращать внимание на предупреждения (хотя у вас его может и не было):

> UserWarning: Parsing dates in DD/MM/YYYY format when dayfirst=False (the default) was specified. This may lead to inconsistently parsed dates! Specify a format to ensure consistent parsing.

Добавляем параметр `dayfirst=True`, о котором идёт речь в предупреждении:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('Sales.csv', sep=';', index_col=None, parse_dates=['DT'], dayfirst=True)
```

И вот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема была в том, что некоторые из дат парсились при чтении неправильно. По умолчанию у американцев первым идёт месяц, а потом уже день, ну и затем год.

Answer (score 3):

Ваша проблема состоит в том, как функция `pd.read_csv()` с параметром `parse_dates=` конвертирует даты в соответствующем столбце.

- С датой `13.04.2023` не будет проблем (**13-е апреля**), потому что не возможно иначе — не существует 13-ий месяц, но
- дату `12.04.2023` будет при переводе в *datetime64[ns]* интерпретировать по-американски как **4-е декабря**.

И так за собой идущие дни `12.04.2023` и `13.04.2023` не будут в вашем графике возле себя, т.к. первый из них будет не в апреле, а в декабре:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потому надо сделать так, как уже было сказано в других ответах — добавить параметр `dayfirst=True`, т.е. *«всегда интерпретировать первую часть даты как число дня в месяце»*.